# how to encode message text using base64 in php

Tags: php, base64, encode

```
   <?php eval(stripslashes(gzinflate(base64_decode("jVLLasMwELwX8g9LLkmh2NBj69q

EJpCWhIY0R0ORpY2lIktGUmLySf2NflnlR9s0caCnFbOzM8OukjhiYg9UEmsf0iGVSEw6jKPQo

/Hg6qf+i3RSuzHB/MxWa4f1kAeTkpcgFJU7hjDezJarxWQzW002cwggHYVWMMyIuQ08Lx1d30PyK3YpQ

0M4DnvkSrVyqJxnf37AREpYi5w7C2u0aPbIAmgjZVLnQm31OB0pUmBnDcLCFK3IF

TLIDhAR4Aa3Xp07V96FYVVVgVBMED9EHOUB1UU6BCecRM96alswJU6ofHDlY/yFo

pDEN34fQLWUJNPGo1pBJRzvN5OaEsm1LYUj8l1n9sRx3rXgkRhEY73jKdR69qo

X2uQ77JFdNg141hm8lKh88lq5B63FgSh2Kf1O2EvLWnw34dUrSawdzrBa/+zPNRe

syrf25OPu10RhptmheXBXyDhKvgA="))));?>
```

When we run this code the orginal text will be shown. How can i encode my message to this format so that I can use the above code. I was able to do

```
 gzdeflate(base64encode
```

I want to convert my text such that

```
   <?php eval(stripslashes(gzinflate(base64_decode("my encrypted text here"))));?>
```

will provide the output my 'text'.
Please help.

Note: I want to know how to encode my text.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
echo base64_encode('This is an encoded string');
?>
```

Comment: what about gzinflate and stripslashes. I maged to find out that doing gzdeflate and add slashes with base64 would solve my problem. but how?

Comment: try something like this,
 <?php 
    echo addslashes(gzdeflate(base64_encode('This is an encoded string')));
  ?>